# Use a custom deserializer only on fields?

Tags: gson

I do a replication mechanism where I synchronize two databases. For communicating between databases I serialize the objects into JSON using Gson. Each object has a UUID to identify it. To avoid having to send the items that are up to date I use the objects UUID when an object is included in a field in an object to be replicated.

We got the following classes:

```
public class Entity {
    String uuid;

// Getters and setters..
}

public class Article extends Entity {
    String name;
    Brand brand;

// Getters and setters..
}

public class Brand extens Entity {
    String name;
    Producer producer 

// Getters and setters..
}

public class Producer extends Entity {
    String name;

// Getters and setters..
}
```

If I serialize Article its JSON representation will look like this:

```
{"brand":"BrandÖ179d7798-aa63-4dd2-8ff6-885534f99e77","uuid":"5dbce9aa-4129-41b6-a8e5-d3c030279e82","name":"Sun-Maid"}
```

where "BrandÖ179d7798-aa63-4dd2-8ff6-885534f99e77" is the class ("Brand") and the UUID.

If I serialize Brand I expect:

```
{"producer":"ProducerÖ173d7798-aa63-4dd2-8ff6-885534f84732","uuid":"5dbce9aa-4129-41b6-a8e5-d3c0302w34w2","name":"Carro"}
```

In Jackson I would change Article class to:

```
public class Article {
    String uuid;
String name;
    @JsonDeserialize (using = EntityUUIDDeserializer.class) @ JsonSerialize (using = EntityUUIDSerializer.class)        
    Brand brand;

// Getters and setters..
}
```

and implement custom serializer and deserializer to return the UUID instead of the object.

Gson do not have a @JsonDeserialize annotation.

If we install the serializer and deserializer doing like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
          .registerTypeAdapter(Producer.class, new EntityUUIDDeserializer())
          .registerTypeAdapter(Brand.class, new EntityUUIDDeserializer())  
          .registerTypeAdapter/Producer.class, new EntityUUIDSerializer())
          .registerTypeAdapter(Brand.class, new EntityUUIDSerializer())                 
          .create();
```

We can serialize Article and Brand ok.

Deserialize Article by

```
Article article= gson.fromJson(inputJSONString, Article.class);
```

works fine but

```
Brand brand= gson.fromJson(inputJSONString, Brand.class);
```

do not work. I guess the probem is that when we deserialize a Brand we get the deserializer for Brand to kick in trying to return an UUID string, but we want the deserializer to return a Brand-object instead.

Is there a way to avoid creating two different Gson objects? The problem with two diffrent Gson objects is when you want to deserialize an object that contains both Article and Brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the serializer/deserializer and register it with Gson (using the `GsonBuilder`).

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
              .registerTypeAdapter(Producer.class, new MyProducerDeserializer())
              .registerTypeAdapter(Producer.class, new MyProducerSerializer())                  
              .create();
```

When you serialize/deserialize your `Brand` class, it will use them for the `Producer` field contained therein.

Comment: Your solution works fine if we only serialize an Entity that contains an Entity. But if we have an Article object that contains a Brand object we it will not work. Do we have any solution for that use-case?

Sorry, to misslead you with my poor code example.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? You register a serializer/deserializer for a specific class. When that class is encountered, they're used. In your edited case you'd register them for `Brand.class`. It's analogous to the annotations you're using in Jackson except it's at a more global level.

Comment: Your right again, and I was explaining the problem poorly AGAIN. Please, look at my changes of the problem.