# Partially modify a java object from json

Tags: java, json, parsing, field, gson

I want to be able to modify a java object from a JSON string without having to specify every field. Example:

```
package controller.test;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Tests {
    public Tests() {
        test();
    }

    private void test() {
        Person realPerson = new Person();
        realPerson.setName("Bobby");
        realPerson.setAge(28);

        // Now trying to set the name from a JSON string
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Person modifiedPerson = gson.fromJson("{\"name\":\"Justin\"}", Person.class);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(realPerson));
        // prints: {"name":"Bobby","age":28}
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(modifiedPerson));
        // prints: {"name":"Justin","age":0}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tests();
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    // Getters & setters are added here
}
```

How can I modify realPerson.name from "Bobby" to "Justin" without having to specify the age?

For a small class like this example it's not really a big problem: I could just check and set each field individually. But my class contains 138 (!) different fields.

EDIT:

My question was maybe poorly explained, let me sum up my problem:

I have an instance of a class (with ~130 different fields that are all set to individual values).

I want to be able to modify values in this instance using a JSON string.

Example JSON string: {"field13": "5", "field100": "2"}

Is there any way to accomplish this without having to write specific code for each field in my java class?

Comment: have you checked this guide? https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer

Comment: I don't really understand what to do here. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Why not `realPerson.setName(modifiedPerson.getName());` ?

Comment: My servlet is handling objects for a client. The client has to be able to set the fields of the java objects using POST requests with stringified JSON objects.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong, you have a class with many fields, and you want to deserialize of an instance of this class using part of the json, related only to one field. Am I right ?

Comment: In other words, when you have a big object, you want to **update** a field of this object via deserialization. Am I right ?

Comment: @BirgerSkogengPedersen check this post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325597/use-a-custom-deserializer-only-on-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an option to use Jackson as deserializer you could use the Annotations in the dataholder:

```
@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, Object value);
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't really understand what to do here, write a deserializer? That was kinda what I was trying to avoid. Could you be a bit more specific on your suggestion?

Comment: When switching to Jackson (instead of gson) as deserializer for Json, all you have to do is add these two Methods to your data model and annotate them. If an field occurs in your json string, which is not covered by the model, Jackson will call the generic setter. (Or in case of serialization it will call the generic getter and add these fields)
Maybe [this](http://vincentdevillers.blogspot.de/2013/08/how-to-map-unknown-json-properties-with.html) will help you to understand it.
Using generic fields enables you to iterate over them, instead of setting each individually.

Comment: The class of the dataholder is not necessarily going to be used for web applications. I've ended up writing a custom parser (really writing a script that wrote it for me).
I'll accept your answer